# How to decrease width between Bootstrap Grids

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is how currently my page looks like

[image]

This is the code of the page

```html
<div class="">
                <!-- form start -->
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2"><label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label pull-left">Old Password</label></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtOldPassword" onchange="DoACommonJs.HideErrorMessage(this)" placeholder="Old Password" maxlength="20">
                                <span toggle="#txtOldPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
    
    
                                <div id="div_txtOldPassword" class="has-error" style="display:none">
                                    <span id="span_txtOldPassword" class="help-block">Old password missing or Incorrect old password.</span>
    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label pull-left">New Password</label></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtNewPassword" onchange="DoACommonJs.HideErrorMessage(this)" onblur="DoAProfileJs.CheckPasswordstrength(this)" placeholder="New Password" maxlength="20">
                                    <span toggle="#txtNewPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                                    <div id="div_txtNewPassword" class="has-error" style="display:none">
                                        <span id="span_txtNewPassword" class="help-block">New password missing.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <label for="inputEmail13" class="control-label pull-left">Confirm Password</label></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtConfirmPassword" onblur="DoAProfileJs.CheckConfirmPassword(this)" onchange="DoACommonJs.HideErrorMessage(this)" placeholder="Confirm Password" maxlength="20">
                                    <span toggle="#txtConfirmPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                                    <div id="div_txtConfirmPassword" class="has-error" style="display:none">
                                        <span id="span_txtConfirmPassword" class="help-block">Confirm password missing.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-body -->
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btnUserPasswordUpdate" href="#" onclick="DoAProfileJs.SaveChangePassword()"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-save fa-lg"></i>Save</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-footer -->
                </form>
            </div>
```

I want to decrease the width/space between the Bootstrapgrids.
I tried changing width of the  `box-body` class but that moves the whole class to the left. Despite Noticing the decrease in the gap.
What could be the possible better ways?

Comment: do you want to reduce the space between the `old password` text and the textbox??

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Yes

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai It's better if I put `Control-label pull-right` 
but I want the names to be aligned at left as well

Comment: As per bootstrap grid alignment, you can't exactly mentioned that width. But you can do the alignment right, so that it looks like always next to each other.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Thanks, but as I said in the above comment, I want the 3 names to be perfectly alligned to the left as well. As they are now (in the pic)
Maybe inserting another class help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add few custom css to customize as per your requirement as given below:

[image]

```css
.custom-form {  font-size: 13px !important;}
.p-0{ padding: 0px !important; }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal custom-form">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1 p-0"><label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label pull-left">Old Password</label></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtOldPassword" onchange="DoACommonJs.HideErrorMessage(this)" placeholder="Old Password" maxlength="20">
                                <span toggle="#txtOldPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
    
    
                                <div id="div_txtOldPassword" class="has-error" style="display:none">
                                    <span id="span_txtOldPassword" class="help-block">Old password missing or Incorrect old password.</span>
    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1 p-0">
                                <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label pull-left">New Password</label></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtNewPassword" onchange="DoACommonJs.HideErrorMessage(this)" onblur="DoAProfileJs.CheckPasswordstrength(this)" placeholder="New Password" maxlength="20">
                                    <span toggle="#txtNewPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                                    <div id="div_txtNewPassword" class="has-error" style="display:none">
                                        <span id="span_txtNewPassword" class="help-block">New password missing.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1 p-0">
                                <label for="inputEmail13" class="control-label pull-left">Confirm Password</label></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtConfirmPassword" onblur="DoAProfileJs.CheckConfirmPassword(this)" onchange="DoACommonJs.HideErrorMessage(this)" placeholder="Confirm Password" maxlength="20">
                                    <span toggle="#txtConfirmPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                                    <div id="div_txtConfirmPassword" class="has-error" style="display:none">
                                        <span id="span_txtConfirmPassword" class="help-block">Confirm password missing.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-body -->
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btnUserPasswordUpdate" href="#" onclick="DoAProfileJs.SaveChangePassword()"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-save fa-lg"></i>Save</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-footer -->
                </form>
```

Comment: This solution will break the label into two lines in some of the resolution.